# Avoid using two arrays to make a simple string change

Tags: python

I've a list with some json file names and I want to remove the `.json` from the words.

What I've done and works is:

```
jsonlist = ['foo.json', 'bar.json']
jsonlist_parsed = []
for i in jsonlist:
    x = i.replace(".json", "")
    jsonlist_parsed.append(x)
```

`jsonlist_parsed` prints me the desired solution, `['foo', 'bar']`

Is there a way to avoid using two arrays and doing the change just in the `jsonlist` array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, like this

```
jsonlist = ['foo.json', 'bar.json']
print [item.replace(".json", "") for item in jsonlist]
# ['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think that the proper solution would be:

```
for pos, i in enumerate(jsonlist):
    jsonlist[pos] = i.replace(".json", "")
```

because if you use list comprehension you are creating another list "on-the-fly". Isnt't it?

Comment: Prefer comprehension, whenever possible. That is very efficient. `jsonlist = List comprehension over jsonlist`. That's it. The old list is ready for garbage collection (unless some other variable refers it).

Comment: I'm not saying that list comprehensions are slow, but I understood that @Borja wanted to avoid creating another list, and that 's exactly what list comprehensions do! *They create another list*. If the list is big enough this could make a difference in memory requirements. If you are going to iterate only once through the modified values you could use a _generator_.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonlist = [item.replace(".json", "") for item in jsonlist]
```

I don't think it's any faster, but it's easier on the eyes, list comprehension ftw.

Edit: @thefourtheye, that answer wasn't there when I opened this lol.